# TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an web app, when splicing an object in a array. All of sudden, I am getting this error in the console that says: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module("Portal", ['ngRoute',  'ui.bootstrap' ]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

$scope.inactive = true;

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', '$state'];

function MainCtrl($scope, $window, $timeout, $state) {
    $scope.deleteAction = function (people) {
        $timeout(function () {
            var index = $scope.userInfo.persons.indexOf(people);
            console.log($scope.userInfo.persons);
            $scope.userInfo.persons.splice(index, 1);
            console.log($scope.userInfo.persons);
            $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
            $window.location.href = '#/person';
        }, 100);
    };
}
```

Comment: Cannot debug your code. What is unclear about this error message? Why should `$state` not be `undefined`?

Comment: `$state` is being defined in the function above. But, the only error is showing is: `go` that is `undefined`.

Comment: @R.Saban You know why is giving me that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not injecting `$state` service. Notice the last parameter in your controller definition:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window, $timeout, $state) {
    $scope.deleteAction = function (people) {
        $timeout(function () {
            var index = $scope.userInfo.persons.indexOf(people);
            console.log($scope.userInfo.persons);
            $scope.userInfo.persons.splice(index, 1);
            console.log($scope.userInfo.persons);
            $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
            $window.location.href = '#/person';
        }, 100);
    };
 });
```

Here is a recomended version of the controller definition, that plays nicely with code uglifiers:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', '$state'];

function MainCtrl($scope, $window, $timeout, $state) {
    $scope.deleteAction = function (people) {
        $timeout(function () {
            var index = $scope.userInfo.persons.indexOf(people);
            console.log($scope.userInfo.persons);
            $scope.userInfo.persons.splice(index, 1);
            console.log($scope.userInfo.persons);
            $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
            $window.location.href = '#/person';
        }, 100);
    };
 });
```

Comment: Should I remove `app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope)` and insert the `app.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);` ?

Comment: I looks ok to mee :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146340/discussion-between-va-dev-and-jramirez).